# clicking Link throws 404 using next 14.1.4

Tags: next.js

In the page `app/page.tsx`

```js
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <main>
            <Link href="/hello">Hello</Link>
        </main>
    );
}
```

The file `hello.tsx` has

```js
import React from "react";

const Hello = () => {
    return (
        <div>
           <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Hello;
```

No matter where I place in the project I place the hello.tsx, I get 404 when clicking on the Link and URL that shows up on 404 is http://localhost:3000/hello

Even Github Copilot is not able to solve the problem.
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR6B0.png)

Answer (score 1):

okay just found that Nextjs 13 and above version needs a
1.) folder `hello` under `app`
2.) and then a page named `page.jsx` inside the folder `hello`